# Netsuite Customer Center: Enter an Order - Customers submitting invoices without terms

Tags: netsuite

We have some customers with Terms and some without. In our Customer Center (My Account section), there's a link to "Enter an Order", which displays an Invoice form by default, because I set the Invoice form to the preferred Sales Order (external) form.

However, what this seems to do is show the invoice form for everyone, regardless of whether they have terms or not.

The behavior I want is: When a customer with terms clicks the "Enter an Order" link it shows them the invoice order form. When a customer without terms clicks the "Enter an Order" link it shows them the credit card order form.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you may also be able to do the same sort of thing with a before load user event script. I'd forgotten about this (first did it years ago)

- create a Sales Order User Event Script.
- for the beforeLoadEvent set up a script like the following:

  ```
  function beforeLoad(type, myForm, req) {

  if (type == 'create' && nlapiGetContext().getRoleCenter() == 'CUSTOMER') {
      if(nlapiGetFieldValue('entity')){// shouldn't be here if no entity
          var hasTerms = nlapiLookupField('customer', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'), 'terms');
          var ccFormId = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_default_custcenter_cash_form');
          var invFormId = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_default_custcenter_inv_form');
          var neededFormId = hasTerms ? invFormId : ccFormId;
          if (req && !req.getParameter('cf') && neededFormId != nlapiGetFieldValue('customform')) {
              nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'sHould redirect to invoice form');
              nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), (type == 'create'), { cf: neededFormId });
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give this a try. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Of course when I looked at this I realized that I'd conflated a couple of scripts. You'll need:
`nlapiSetRedirectURL('TASKLINK', 'EDIT_TRAN_SALESORD', null , true, { cf: neededFormId });`

The code I posted was hacked from the same thing but that controlled editing the record(you might need that as well)

Comment: in the above, where does nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_default_custcenter_cash_form'); come from? should that be the same for everyone? I'm getting null on both that and the invoice form line.

Comment: Those are from script parameters on the user event script. They are described in the docs. 
The problem is that by default Netsuite only lets you define one form as the "preferred" form for each role but you need to juggle at least two forms to achieve your goal. 
Your script parameters will be of type List/Record - Transaction Form

Comment: So they should just work, as is? When I run the above ccFormId is null and invFormId is null, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I got it, sorry. It's still early here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it's a bit of a hack.

Basically you create two links to enter an order in your customer center. Each is the same except one has `&cf=<internalidoftermsform>`

Then in your theme you add a new tag say `<TAB_EXTRA_FOOTER>` which is blank in the tag definition

then in on the my account tab you override that tag with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){
    var custTerms ="<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer', 'terms', '')%>";

    $("a...).hide(); // filter out and hide the wrong link. Or just add the cf param to the existing link 

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

The basic idea is to just use the injected script to adjust the links so the correct one is present.